# Running Cucumber from different directory using Gradle 5 and Cucumber-JVM

Tags: java, gradle, cucumber, build.gradle, cucumber-jvm

I'm fairly new to Gradle and am using version 5.0. I'm reasonably proficient in Cucumber.

I've got a simple project that builds a jar file and runs JUnit tests on them. It all works well.
Now I want to add Cucumber to the project but I want my .feature files and the related stepdefs in an alternative source-tree (sourceSet in Gradle terminology).

The sources can be found on [Github](https://github.com/ThreeAxis/hellocucumber), which holds a sample project.

My source tree should look like this:

```
src/
    cucumberTest/
        java/
            /...
        resources/
            /...
    main/
        java/
            /...
        resources/
            /...
    test/
        /java
            /...
        resources/
            /...
```

When I put the .feature files in cucumberTest/resources and the stepdef java files in test/java my Cucumber tests run fine. But when the stepdefs are in cucumberTest/java Cucumber can't find the files and I get the error that they are not defined.

```
Undefined scenarios:
src/cucumberTest/resources/is_it_saturday_yet.feature:4 # Sunday isn't Saturday

2 Scenarios (1 undefined, 1 passed)
6 Steps (1 skipped, 2 undefined, 3 passed)
0m0.134s
```

My build.gradle file is this:

```
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
    id 'java'
    id 'idea'
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}

archivesBaseName = "helloworld"
version = '1.0'

dependencies {
    api 'org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1'

    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:26.0-jre'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile("junit:junit:4.12")
    testCompile('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.3.2')
    testCompile('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:5.3.2')

    testRuntime('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.3.2')
    testRuntime("org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:5.3.2")

    testCompile 'io.cucumber:cucumber-java:4.2.0'
    testCompile 'io.cucumber:cucumber-junit:4.2.0'
}

configurations {
    cucumberRuntime {
        extendsFrom testRuntime
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform ()
    testLogging {
        events "passed", "skipped", "failed"
    }
}

// Cucumber stuff:

sourceSets {
    cucumberTest {
        compileClasspath += sourceSets.main.output
        runtimeClasspath += sourceSets.main.output
    }
}

configurations {
    cucumberTestImplementation.extendsFrom implementation
    cucumberTestRuntimeOnly.extendsFrom runtimeOnly
}

dependencies {
    testCompile 'io.cucumber:cucumber-java:4.2.0'
    testCompile 'io.cucumber:cucumber-junit:4.2.0'
}

task cucumberTest() {
    dependsOn assemble, compileTestJava
    doLast {
        javaexec {
            main = "cucumber.api.cli.Main"
            classpath = configurations.cucumberRuntime + sourceSets.main.output + sourceSets.test.output + sourceSets.cucumberTest.output
            args = ['--plugin', 'pretty', '--glue', 'stepdefs.hellocucumber', 'src/cucumberTest/resources']
        }
    }
}

wrapper {
    gradleVersion = '5.0'
}
```

I've looked all over the web, but I feel like I'm the only one who wants to use cucumber-jvm with Gradle 5 and have the BDD tests (cucumber) separated from the TDD tests (JUnit).

I can take the easy route and just mix them both, but apart from being a little puritan and have BDD and TDD separated, I also want to understand what's going on and why it's not working.

Help is appreciated. Thanks.

Iwan

Comment: I would suggest [Gradle and Cucumber-JVM](http://www.thinkcode.se/blog/2015/12/26/gradle-and-cucumberjvm) and [Getting Started With Gradle: Integration Testing](https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/gradle/getting-started-with-gradle-integration-testing/)

Comment: Thanks MikeJRamsey56. It got me getting further in my quest, but eventually it turned out that with a CucumberTest class it started to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of Bart Kors, a good friend of mine, I was able to get it to work as intended. I updated the Github repository to include the working code. Do a clone of [TrheeAxis/hellocucumber](https://github.com/ThreeAxis/hellocucumber) to get the working code.